# while loop repeats once when it should stop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

This while loop should stop when option = "e", but when option = "e" it somehow sets option to "" (I've checked that with the debugger) and runs again (although option = "") is out of the while loop, it only stops if you set option equal to "e" twice. Option is not a global variable so the fucntions are unable to change its value.

I already tried using while True: and a break command when option = "e" but it does not break out of the loop

```
option = ""
hand = {0:0}
while option != "e":
    option = input("Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end game: ")
    if option == 'n':
        hand = dealHand(HAND_SIZE)
        playHand(hand,wordList,HAND_SIZE)
    elif option == 'r':
        if 0 in hand:
            print("You have not played a hand yet. Please play a new hand first!","\n")
        else:
            playHand(hand,wordList,HAND_SIZE)
    elif option != "e":
        print("Invalid command.")
```

I expect it to break out of the loop if I type "e" (no quotation marks) when it asks me "Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end game: "

Comment: The code you posted certainly does not behave the way you describe; there must be something else going on in the code you didn't post.  We appreciate it when you reduce your code to a minimal example - but you need to verify that it still exhibits the problem!

Comment: I know, you are right, I just forgot to copy the code just below this which was what was causing the problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is what you expect. I tried to recreate the above-mentioned error, I couldn't recreate it. Let me know if you get it again.

```
option = ""
hand = {0:0}
while True:
    option = input("Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end game: ")
    if option == 'n':
        hand = dealHand(HAND_SIZE)
        playHand(hand,wordList,HAND_SIZE)
    elif option == 'r':
        if 0 in hand:
            print("You have not played a hand yet. Please play a new hand first!","\n")
        else:
            playHand(hand,wordList,HAND_SIZE)
    elif option == "e":
        break
    elif option != "e":
        print("Invalid command.")
```

Comment: Didn'tyou read the comment where he said the actual problem is in different code?